# XSLT - How to get the same xml element values in one <fo:block> xslt-fo

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm converting xml to xsl-fo... In the below XML How to get the value of same xml element `<cd>`.

**XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <header>
    <child-A>
        <element>
            <cd>100</cd>
            <cd>message</cd>
            <example>text</example>
        </element>
    </child-A>
    <child-B>
        <element>
            <cd>10</cd>
            <cd>test</cd>
            <example>textB</example>
            <cd>testvalue</cd>
        </element>
    <child-/B>
</header>
```

In this Xml I want to get the value of all `<cd>` xml elements in child-A/element/(both cd elements value).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/header">      
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="child-A/element">   
   <fo:block>      
    <xsl:value-of select="cd">
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I'm getting the first value of  element but not the second..

Output I get

```
<fo:block>100<fo:block>
```

Output I want

```
<fo:block>100
 message</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2 (or 3) with an XSLT 2 (or 3) processor you can use `<xsl:value-of select="cd"/>` to get the string concatenation of all `cd` elements. With XSLT 1 and an XSLT 1 processor push the `cd` elements to another template e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>` or process them with `xsl:for-each select="cd"` with an `xsl:value-of select="."` inside.